# How to get around javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Ok so I have divs on my webpage that when clicked are assigned a variable. I need to access these variables later on when another button is clicked to include them in the email I send. My var mailbody works as it is a local variable I think. But if I replace it with frameColour then it won't work as it isn't global. How can I get around this?

```
$('#purple').click (function() {
            $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
            var frameColour = "purple";
    });

$("#button").click (function() {
    var mailbody = "hello world.";
    window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=' + mailbody);
});
```

Comment: You can't "get around scope".

Comment: You can declare variable before your function

Comment: Really? There must be some way that perhaps keeps my functionality but has the variables as global.

Comment: you could declare your frameColour outside the function and just set it on click.

Comment: @dunn_rite - if both are inside `document.ready` (they should be) - `$(function(){ /* here */ });` - that is not *global* scope, just a scope that is a little broader.

Comment: I could but the variable needs to activate on click as the variables will change depending on user options. Unless there is a way to change a global variable from inside the function?

Comment: ah ok. There are inside a document.ready so I suppose so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `frameColour` to be available in other functions, you have to move its scope up; to prevent adding it to the global scope, you can wrap related functions up in another function, i.e.:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var frameColour;

    $('#purple').click (function() {
        $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
        frameColour = "purple";
    });

    $("#button").click (function() {
        var mailbody = "hello world.";
        // you can use frameColour here
        window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=' + mail body);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I have them in a document.ready. Would this count if it moved the variables up?

Comment: @dunn_rite The `jQuery(function($) { ... });` construct I'm using there is basically the document ready function, so the same rules could be applied :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do the declaration before your "click scope".

```
var frameColour;

$('#purple').click (function() {
            $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
             frameColour = "purple";
    });

$("#button").click (function() {
    var mailbody = "hello world.";
    window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=' + mailbody);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try do delacare it outside the function.

```
var frameColour    
$('#purple').click (function() {
        $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
        frameColour = "purple";
});

$("#button").click (function() {
    var mailbody = "hello world.";
    window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=MyFrame&body=' + mailbody);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable i a higher scope, then change the value from inside your function.

```
var frameColour;
$('#purple').click (function() {
            $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
            frameColour = "purple";
});

$("#button").click (function() {
    var mailbody = "hello world.";
    window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=' + mailbody);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable by declaring your variable outside your function scopes:

```
var global_frameColour = "purple";  

$('#purple').click (function() {
   $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
   global_frameColour = "purple";
});

$("#button").click (function() {
    var mailbody = "hello world.";

    mailbody += global_frameColour;
    window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=' + mailbody);
});
```

If you don't want your variable to be global, you can create a auto-executing wrapper. Any variables declared within here (using the `var` keyword) will be scoped only to the anonymous function. See below

```
(function (){ // declare an anonymous function

    var scoped_frameColour = "purple";  

    $('#purple').click (function() {
      $(".border").css("fill", "#763d81");
      scoped_frameColour = "purple";
    });

    $("#button").click (function() {
      var mailbody = "hello world.";

      mailbody += scoped_frameColour;
      window.open('mailto:sales@beauxcadeaux.co.uk?subject=My Frame&body=' + mailbody);
   });

})(); // this line is important as it executes the anon function

console.log(scoped_frameColour); // undefined; out of scope
```